# Foreach statement inside $query->andWhere()

Tags: php, symfony, foreach, doctrine, query-builder

I need to create a query with Doctrine QueryBuilder using a foreach statement, currently, the following one is used but is not the most correct:

```php
// $query object
foreach ($searches as $value) {
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->orX(
        $query->expr()->eq('c.firstName', ':name'),
        $query->expr()->eq('c.lastName', ':name')
    ))->setParameter('name', $value);
}
```

this gives me :

> ....WHERE ....
>
> AND (a0_.first_name = ? OR a0_.last_name = ?)
>
> AND (a0_.first_name = ? OR a0_.last_name = ?)
>
> ORDER BY a0_.first_name ASC

while I need:

> ...WHERE .....
>
> AND (a0_.first_name = ? OR a0_.last_name = ? OR a0_.first_name = ? OR a0_.last_name = ?)
>
> ORDER BY a0_.first_name ASC

I need something like this, but PHP doesn't allow it of course:

```php
// $query object
$query->andWhere($query->expr()->orX(
    foreach ($searches as $value) {
        $query->expr()->eq('c.firstName', ':name'),
        $query->expr()->eq('c.lastName', ':name')
    }
))
->setParameter('name', $value);
```

Could you please help me use the foreach statement to reach my goal? Your usual help is appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense. What you expect from query like `a0_.first_name = ? OR a0_.first_name = ? ` ?  20 repetitions are as good as a single `a0_.first_name = ?`

Comment: Forget the loop. Use Laravel's [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: @AlexBlex, $searches is an array coming from a preg_split. I must use each array value as search in first and last name

Comment: Ah, I see now. Was confused by your `:name` parameter. If you meant `:name1`, `:name2` etc for each iteration, than follow @StuartWagner's advice.

Comment: @StuartWagner, thank you for the link, I think I already used this to no avail, I have found a solution (sometimes you spend hours trying to find a solution till you post a question on SO :)); I will post as answer in the sake of sharing

Answer (score 7):

For everybody needing one of the solutions:

```php
if (!empty($search)) {
    $orX = $query->expr()->orX();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($searches as $value) {
        $orX->add($query->expr()->eq('c.firstName', ':name'.$i));
        $orX->add($query->expr()->eq('c.lastName', ':name'.$i));
        $query->setParameter('name'.$i, $value);
        $i++;
    }
    $query->andWhere($orX);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work very well. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your objective, though.

Comment: @StuartWagner, this is working Sir; and I will tell you why WhereIn doesn' work for me. but could you please tell me what might be a problem when using something like this? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is working as you expect? You are using a single `:name` parameter, and overwrite it on each iteration.

Comment: Also, there is no need for second loop. `$query->andWhere($query->expr()->orX($ORs));` does equally well and is more readable.

Comment: Must keep placeholder `:name` dynamic inside the loop. Something like `:name_1`, `:name_2` etc.

Comment: @Jeet, yeah that's what I did in my last edit; any additionnal remark is highly appreciated thanks

Comment: @AlexBlex, your second remark gives unfortunately :Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given. But the solution I gave as edit allow removal of second foreach ;-)

Comment: Please do like @Jeet said. The `setParameter($value, $value)` construction is extremely fragile and works only for single-word values.

Comment: @AlexBlex, again thanks, but I am sure these are single word values thanks to '$searches = preg_split('/\s+/', $search);' is there any other reason that makes it more fragile.? thanks a lot

Comment: Everything that doesn't meet DQL/PDO naming convention. Don't remember from top of my head, but I'd assume quotes, question and exclamation marks, most of ASCII codes > 127, etc. Why to bother, if you can do it right without putting unnecessary assumptions on what values should be?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. WhereIn approach may be a bit more idiomatic, yet your one should do the job. I believe you can accept it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex :) @AlexBlex

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this aproche by Using CONCAT and IN Array

```
->where("CONCAT(CONCAT(c.firstName, '_'),c.lastName) IN (:names)")->setParameter('names', $names)
```

the variable $names like this

```
array(firstName_lastName,firstName1_lastName,firstName2_lastName2,...);
```